# How to extract elements from matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python and I've made a matrix with hundreds of rows and just 2 columns.

I've built the matrix like this using numpy:

```
FILE = np.array(
    [
[11,12],
[21,22],
[31,32],
[41,42]
[51,52]
......
    ])
```

I hope this is correct.

Let's say I want to extract only the first 3 elements of the first column (which are 11, 21 and 31): what's the easiest way to do it?

Is there any numpy utility for it?

Comment: Just `FILE[:3,0]`?

Comment: Use indexing: `FILE[:3,0]`.

Comment: It is called "slicing"… `FILE[:3,0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slicing here. So `0:3`, or more succinctly `:3` are the first three rows, then the next `0` refers to the first column.

```
>>> FILE[0:3, 0]
array([11, 21, 31])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the 1st three rows of column 0:

```
FILE[0:3, 0]
```